# T-SQL implicit vs. explicit casting for DATE datatype

Tags: sql-server

When taking a DATETIME value and changing it to a DATE value in T-SQL, should the CAST be performed explicitly or not?  For example:

```
DECLARE @Today_NoCast DATE = GETDATE();
DECLARE @Today_Cast DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);

SELECT [GETDATE()] = GETDATE();

SELECT
[@Today_NoCast] = @Today_NoCast,
[@Today_Cast] = @Today_Cast;
```

[image: GETDATE]

[image: Today]

Both @Today_NoCast and @Today_Cast give the desired result.  But what is considered "best practice"?

Comment: Depends on your requirement. Sometimes we add field as DATETIME as per project requirement requirement but at the time of doing select we need to cast. Best practice is to use data type as per requirement and avoid additional operations such as CAST wherever possible.

Comment: In the code you posted there is no benefit to the explicit cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the datatype in `Date`. You don't have to do a `explicit` conversion.

so avoid using the `explicit` conversion

Answer (score 1):

As far as SQL Server is concerned there is no difference in this case - both the implicit (no CAST) and explicit conversion will produce the same result.

However, from a code maintenance point of view there is a slight difference. The implicit conversion is just another line of code, probably (based on my experience, no reflection on you!) without any comments or documentation or anything else. The explicit conversion in the same place also says "the person who wrote this code knows that GETDATE returns a DATETIME but they don't want the TIME part so are deliberately just saving it into a DATE".

It's not making one line more maintainable that counts, it's taking the approach to all of your work that makes a difference in the long run.

Rhys

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is what is called an "implicit conversion". In otherwords SQL Server guesses the best way to convert it. These conversions are on a [pretty diagram on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx). As SQL Server will do it implicitly, there is no need for you to do it explicitly. You are just adding noise.

Personally i like to do the minimum amount of date manipulation possible. Otherwise what you tend to find is people casting them all over the place causing code smells.

If you need the time portion and are consequently storing the time, you can format-away the time in the UI if required.

If you find you need queries that are creating WHERE clauses on your date with a time, consider separating the date and the time into separate fields to prevent SEARCHARGs i.e. developers wrapping functions around your indexed columns in the where clause which prevents the optimizer from using the index, therefore reducing performance.